# How can I count checkbox check from many forms?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to count how many boxes are checked. I am having trouble because it counts all the checkbox checks, but I want to count checkboxes from each article and show it on there separate boxesChecked div. `article01 checks = boxesChecked-01,article02 checks = boxesChecked-02`. I tried different IDs method to know where to innerhtml() count, but as you can see that doesn't work.

```js
var form = $(".checkform");
var checkBoxes = $(form).children('.checkbox');
var count = 0;

$(checkBoxes).on('click', function() {
  var id = $(form).attr("id").split("-")[1]
  $.each(checkBoxes, function(i) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked) {
      count++;
    }
  });

  var divBoxesChecked = document.getElementById('boxesChecked-' + id);
  divBoxesChecked.innerHTML = 0;
  divBoxesChecked.innerHTML = count;
  count = 0;
});
```

```css
/*CONTENT*/

.content01 {
  width: 69%;
}

.eventsbtn {
  color: #3f2916;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  font-size: 26px;
  background: none;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 284px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-family: 'Crete Round', serif;
}

h2.events {
  padding: 18px;
}

#line {
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-color: #ffeb6b;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 92px;
  width: 800px;
}

#line02 {
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
  border-color: #ffeb6b;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 18px;
  width: 800px;
}

.checkbox {
  display: flex;
  /*margin-bottom: 26px;*/
  /*float: left;*/
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type='checkbox'] {
  /*margin-top: 32px;*/
  transform: scale(1.7);
  margin-right: 38px;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.article_block {
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.article_title {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.article_content {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  width: 65%;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.content02 {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 36px;
}

.content02 img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.button01 {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

.button02 {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttonDone {
  background-color: #a62300;
  width: 212px;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  outline: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.buttonClass {
  background-color: #a62300;
  width: 212px;
  height: 60px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  outline: none;
}

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: #3b3530;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.footer_content {
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

a {
  color: #ffe756;
}


/*POPUP*/

.button {
  font-size: 18px;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  color: #ffe756;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  color: #3f2916;
}

.popup p {
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: 'rubik', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  /*border-radius: 5px;*/
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'rubik', sans-serif;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}

.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>ARTICLE1</h3>
<div id="boxesChecked-01"></div>

<div class="article01 panel">

  <form class="checkform" id="form-01">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box_01" class="checkbox" name="box_01" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block"><div class="content02"><img src="article_img1.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST1</h3><p class="article_content">1820: TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_02" class="checkbox" name="box_02" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img2.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_03" class="checkbox" name="box_03" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img3.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_04" class="checkbox" name="box_04" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img4.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_05" class="checkbox" name="box_05" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img5.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_06" class="checkbox" name="box_06" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img6.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_07" class="checkbox" name="box_07" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img7.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>
  </form>
</div>
<h3>ARTICLE2</h3>
<div id="boxesChecked-02"></div>
<div class="article02 panel">
  <form class="checkform" id="form-02">
    <input type="checkbox" id="box_01" class="checkbox" name="box_01" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block"><div class="content02"><img src="article_img1.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST1</h3><p class="article_content">1820: TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_02" class="checkbox" name="box_02" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img2.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_03" class="checkbox" name="box_03" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img3.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_04" class="checkbox" name="box_04" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img4.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_05" class="checkbox" name="box_05" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img5.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_06" class="checkbox" name="box_06" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img6.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="box_07" class="checkbox" name="box_07" />
    <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img7.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: do it once for each article, collecting only the child checkbox elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just looping through all `form` elements ***once*** to find checked checkboxes, you need to loop through ***each*** form once.

And, you don't need to loop over the checkboxes to find out how many are checked. Just use a selector with the `:checked` pseudo-class to get them into a set and look at the `length` of that set.

```js
// We want to get a set of all the form elements
var $forms = $("form");

// Loop over each form
$forms.each(function(idx, frm){

  // Set up click event handlers for each checkbox
  $(".checkbox", frm).on('click', function() {
    // Just set the output element's text to the count of the checked
    // checkboxes in the current form being enumerated
    $("." + frm.id).text(frm.id + " has " + $(".checkbox:checked", frm).length + " checked checkboxes.");
  });
});
```

```css
/*CONTENT*/
.content01{
 width: 69%;
}
.eventsbtn{
 color:#3f2916;
 outline: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 10px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 font-size: 26px;
 background:none;
 text-align: left;
 overflow: auto;
 width: 284px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 clear: both;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 font-family: 'Crete Round', serif;
}
h2.events  {
 padding:18px;
}
#line{
 border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-color: #ffeb6b;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 92px;
    width: 800px;
}
#line02{
 border-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-color: #ffeb6b;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 18px;
    width: 800px;

}
.checkbox{
 display: flex;
 /*margin-bottom: 26px;*/
 /*float: left;*/
 cursor: pointer;
}
input[type='checkbox'] {
 /*margin-top: 32px;*/
 transform: scale(1.7);
 margin-right: 38px;
 /*position: absolute;*/
}


.article_block{
 clear: both;
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
.article_title{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
.article_content {
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 width: 65%;
 font-size: 14px;

}
.content02{
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-left: 36px;
}
.content02 img{
 float: left;
 margin-right: 20px;
}
.button01{
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 text-align: center;
}
.button02{
 display: block; 
 clear: both;
 text-align: center;
}
.buttonDone{
 background-color: #a62300;
 width: 212px;
 height: 60px;
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 margin-top: 70px;
 outline: none;
 font-family: arial;
 font-weight: 600;
}
.buttonClass{
 background-color: #a62300;
 width: 212px;
 height: 60px;
 color: white;
 font-weight: 600;
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 25px;
 border-radius: 12px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 outline: none;
}
.footer { 
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 3rem;
  background-color: #3b3530;
  text-align: left;
 
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 .footer_content{
  max-width: 1024px;
  margin:0 auto;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 25px;
 }
a {
 color:#ffe756;
}
/*POPUP*/
.button {
  font-size: 18px;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  color: #ffe756;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.popup h2 {
 color:#3f2916;
}
.popup p {
  margin-top: 0em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-family: 'rubik', sans-serif;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  /*border-radius: 5px;*/
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'rubik', sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>ARTICLE1</h3>
<div id="boxesChecked-01"></div>
  <div class="article01 panel">
    <form class="checkform" id="form-01">
      <input type="checkbox" id="box_01" class="checkbox" name="box_01" />
      <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block">
        <div class="content02"><img src="article_img1.png">
        <h3 class="article_title">TEST1</h3><p class="article_content">1820: TEST</p></div></div>
      </label>

      <input type="checkbox" id="box_02" class="checkbox" name="box_02" />
      <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02">
        <img src="article_img2.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div>
      </label>

                     <input type="checkbox" id="box_03" class="checkbox" name="box_03" />
                     <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img3.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                     <input type="checkbox" id="box_04" class="checkbox" name="box_04" />
                     <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img4.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                     <input type="checkbox" id="box_05" class="checkbox" name="box_05" />
                     <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img5.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                     <input type="checkbox" id="box_06" class="checkbox" name="box_06"/>
                     <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img6.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                     <input type="checkbox" id="box_07" class="checkbox" name="box_07" />
                     <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img7.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                    </form>


                    </div>
                    <h3>ARTICLE2</h3>
<div id="boxesChecked-02"></div>
    <div class="article02 panel">

                        <form class="checkform" id="form-02">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="box_01" class="checkbox" name="box_01" />
                         <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block"><div class="content02"><img src="article_img1.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST1</h3><p class="article_content">1820: TEST</p></div></div></label>

                         <input type="checkbox" id="box_02" class="checkbox" name="box_02" />
                         <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img2.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                         <input type="checkbox" id="box_03" class="checkbox" name="box_03" />
                         <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img3.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                         <input type="checkbox" id="box_04" class="checkbox" name="box_04" />
                         <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img4.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                         <input type="checkbox" id="box_05" class="checkbox" name="box_05" />
                         <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img5.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                         <input type="checkbox" id="box_06" class="checkbox" name="box_06"/>
                         <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img6.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                         <input type="checkbox" id="box_07" class="checkbox" name="box_07" />
                         <label class="checkbox"><div class="article_block" ><div class="content02"><img src="article_img7.png"><h3 class="article_title">TEST</h3><p class="article_content">TEST</p></div></div></label>

                        </form>


                        </div>
                        
<div class="form-01"></div>
<div class="form-02"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate each form then traverse up to the display div

```
$('.checkform').each(function(){
   var $form =  $(this)
   var checkCount = $form.find(':checkbox:checked').length;
   $form.parent().prev().text('Checked count: ' +checkCount );
});
```

Would be simpler if you used common class names instead of incrementing classes.

You use the same class on the forms throughout....do the same with the other common main elements